# ¿Como extraer objetos de api "mi indicador economico" con c++?

Tags: c++

He intentado de todo para poder obtener el valor del dolar, logre hacerlo por consola en linux pero necesito hacerlo con QT y no me reconoce la libreria, alguna ayuda? dejo el codigo que funcionaba

````
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    CURL *curl;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl){
        CURLcode res;
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://mindicador.cl/api/euro");
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        //response = curl_easy_getfnfo(curl, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE, &ct);
        if(CURLE_OK == res) {
            char *ct;
            res = curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE, &ct);
            if((CURLE_OK == res) && ct) printf("We received Content-Type: %s\n", ct);
        }
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Es [tag:c++] o [tag:c]? Ve a [edit] y usa la etiqueta correcta, algo va de uno al otro :)

Comment: Hay que ver dónde tienes los archivos y las opciones de compilación.

Comment: @Mateo La libreria no viene instalada por default?

Comment: La única configuración por defecto comprende la librería estándar y las cabeceras del sistema operativo. El resto de cabeceras, puedes incluirlas por su ruta relativa entre comillas (`#include "ruta/a/cabecera.h"`) o tienes que configurar los directorios donde buscar archivos .h (varía según el compilador).

Comment: Qt tiene clases específicas para lo que pretendes: [QNetworkAccessManager](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qnetworkaccessmanager.html).